# GeoXML3 status when kml is rendered

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, geoxml3

Is it possible to determine when the geoXML3 is finished rendering an entire KML file? I was unable to find any reference API related to this library.

```
geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
                map: map,
                infoWindow: infowindow,
                singleInfoWindow: true,
        processStyles: true,
         zoom: geoZoom,
        suppressInfoWindows:true,
                afterParse: addListen
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for [the "parsed" event](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/issues/detail?id=40). I can look at merging in famille's update, it has been a while since I looked at that.  The documentation (such as it exists) is at: https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/w/list

Comment: Yeah I will look into that. I am trying to get KML layers to render ontop of these parsed out client side google objects but it doesnt seem to be working. even adding it in the ' afterParse: addListen' didnt seem to do it

Comment: bummer. even if I use that 'fix'. And I render the geoxml3 polygons and then call a funtion on a 5 second timer to render some kml layer. The kml layer will be behind it. I guess I could have it parse all of the layers out, but I was hoping to not do that since with 5000 markers it would be slow.

Comment: Native Google Maps Javascript API Markers and Polygons will always render above KmlLayers (unless you start modifying the map panes that they are rendered on).  You can only control layering between KmlLayers, and between native Google Maps objects.

Comment: Ah, okay I guess I am going to stick with KML for this project and have one client side marker which does not impede view. I appreciate the help you have provided me over the past few weeks.